# Why is this code fragment returning unexpected results?

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

I am currently learning C++ at my school, and am making a word sleuth as part of a project that I have to submit. For this, I have already made the grid of alphabets and other necessary things (clues, rules, etc.). I am taking the input in the form of coordinates in an integer array whereby the user enters 4 values in the array, signifying the initial row and column number and the final row and column number, corresponding to which are the first and last alphabets of a particular word.

After doing this, I am now comparing the array input by the user with the array I have already defined that has the coordinates of that particular word. This is shown here :

```
    cout<<"Enter the coordinates of starting and final characters : row1 col1 row2 col2 "<<endl;
    for (z = 0; z < 4; z++)      //first for loop
        cin>>p[z];              //taking the input as an array 'p'

    for (b = 0; b < 4; b++)        //second for loop
    {
        if (p[b] == messi[b])
            b+=0;
    }
    if (b == 4)
        cout<<"Great!!!! You have answered the question correctly"<<"\n\n";
    else
        cout<<"You got this one wrong mate! Try again :)"<<"\n\n";
```

Here, messi[b] is the array which has the coordinates corresponding to the word 'MESSI' in the grid. Now, to my mind, the 'if' statement after the second for loop must contain the condition to check if b = 3. However, when I do that, the output always comes out to be what the 'else' statement says i.e. "You got this..." for every input. However, when I impose the condition to check if b = 4, the output comes out to be what the 'if' statement says i.e. "Great!!..." for every input.

What wrong am I doing? I hope I am clear enough in explaining the problem to you. I am using CodeBlocks 16.01.

Comment: What do you expect from `b+=0;` ? And what do you expect from enclosing  loop ?

Comment: can you paste you output

Comment: Well, my output screen does not allow me to copy content from there.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit unclear what you are doing, as the program stands, `b` will always be equal to 4 after the second `for`-loop since the last time to condition was true, `b < 4`. So after the increment, it **will** be 4.

Inside the second `for`-loop you also have the NOP code `b += 0;` which does absolutely nothing to the code. What is the intention here?

Comment: Oh I just figured out what the error was. I have rectified it now. Probably I was not clear enough in explaining the issue. Thanks anyway.